# AVL tree implementation step by step

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, avl-tree

First of, I did read so many topics on stack concerning avl trees, but I'm having problems to understand implementation presented by other users.

I'm familiar with the idea of AVL tree, the way it balances itself and I know how to implement standard BST tree, which is quite helpful, but I can't find on the Internet a single piece of **C++ AVL Implementation with step by step introduction**, what I'm trying to do is to find some material which will allow me to understand in the easiest way what is going on with the code.

I guess, there are some many IT students/graduates on stack who possibly can help me out with their academic scripts, unfortunately I did not find anything interesting while using uncle Google.

All I found is some pieces of incomplete code, while I'm looking for implementation which includes: **tree structure, all balancing functions with some explanation how it's done & print-in-order/delete/insert node functions as well**

http://kukuruku.co/hub/cpp/avl-trees is quite helpful, but still it's lacking some basic explanation and I simply can't get my head around this thing.

Comment: This video is really good for AVL trees. The whole course is amazing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNeL18KsWPc

Comment: Do you want a template implementation?  If not, then I have a good C AVL tree and would be willing to answer any questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

@ Chris M   I think this code might help you..Its simple program to implement a Dictionary using AVL tree

```
 "#include "iostream "  <br>
 #include "string.h"  <br>
using namespace std;  <br>
class node  <br>
{  <br>
   //int data;  <br>
   char key[10],mean[10];  <br>
   node *left,*right;  <br>
   int ht;  <br>
};  <br>

class AVL  <br>
{
  public:  <br>
  node *root;  <br>
  node *insert(node *,char[], char[]);//Recursive counterpart of insert  <br>
  node *Delete1(node *,char[]);//Recursive counterpart of delete  <br>
  void  preorder1(node *); //Recursive counterpart of preorder  <br>
  void  inorder1(node *); //Recursive counterpart of inorder  <br>

  node *rotateright(node *);  <br>
  node *rotateleft(node *);  <br>
  node *RR(node *);  <br>
  node *LL(node *);  <br>
  node *LR(node *);  <br>
  node *RL(node *);
  int height(node *);  <br>
  int BF(node *);  <br>
      AVL()
      {
    root=NULL;
      }
     void create(char *x,char *y)  <br>
     {
     root=insert(root,x,y);  <br>
     }
     void Delete(char *x)  <br>
     {
     root=Delete1(root,x);  <br>
     }

     void levelwise();
     void makenull()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }
};
int main()
{
    AVL A;
    char k[20],m[20];
    int n,i,op;

    do
        {
            cout<<"\n1)Create : ";  <br>
            cout<<"\n2)Insert : ";  <br>
            cout<<"\n3)Delete : ";  <br>
            cout<<"\n4)Print  : ";  <br>
            cout<<"\n5)Quit   : ";  <br>
            cout<<"\nEnter Your Choice : ";  <br>
            cin >> op;  <br>
            switch(op)  <br>
                {
                case 1:cout<<"\nEnter no.of elements :";  <br>
                       cin>>n;  <br>
                       cout<<"\n Enter key and its meaning:";  <br>
                       A.makenull();  <br>
                       for(i=0;i<n;i++)  <br>
                       {
                        cin>>k;  <br>
                        cin>>m;  <br>
                        A.create(k,m);  <br>
                       }
                       break;  <br>
                case 2:cout<<"\n Enter key and its meaning:";
                       cin >>k;
                       cin >>m;
                       A.create(k,m);
                       break;
                case 3:cout<<"\n Enter key to be deleted:";  <br>
                       cin >>k;
                       A.Delete(k);  <br>
                       break;
                case 4: cout<<"\nPreorder sequence :\n";  <br>
                    A.preorder1(A.root);
                    cout<<"\nInorder sequence :\n";  <br>
                    A.inorder1(A.root);  v
                    //A.levelwise();
                    break;  <br>
                 }

    }while(op!=5);  <br>
return 0;

}
node * AVL::insert(node *T,char *k,char *m)  <br>
{
int i;
    if(T==NULL)
    {
        T=new node;
        strcpy(T->key,k);  <br>
        strcpy(T->mean,m);  <br>
        T->left=NULL;  <br>
        T->right=NULL;  <br>
    }  <br>
    else
       {
        for(int i=0;i<=strlen(k);i++)
        {
        if(k[i] > T->key[i])                // insert in right subtree
        { 
            T->right=insert(T->right,k,m);  <br>
            if(BF(T)==-2)  <br>
                if(k [i] >T->right->key[i])  <br>
                    T=RR(T);
                else
                    T=RL(T);
            break;
        }
        else
            //if(x<T->key)
         {
            T->left=insert(T->left,k,m);  <br>
            if(BF(T)==2)
                if(k[i] < T->left->key[i])  <br>
                    T=LL(T);  <br>
                else
                    T=LR(T);
            break;
          }
           }
        }
          T->ht=height(T);
          return(T);
}

int AVL::height(node *T)  v
{
    int lh,rh;
    if(T==NULL)  <br>
        return(0);
    if(T->left==NULL)  v
        lh=0;
    else
        lh=1+T->left->ht;  <br>
    if(T->right==NULL)
        rh=0;
    else
        rh=1+T->right->ht;  <br>
    if(lh>rh)
        return(lh);
    return(rh);
}
node * AVL::rotateright(node *x)  <br>
{
    node *y;
    y=x->left;
    x->left=y->right;
    y->right=x;
    x->ht=height(x);
    y->ht=height(y);
    return(y);
}
node * AVL::rotateleft(node *x)  <br>
{
    node *y;
    y=x->right;
    x->right=y->left;
    y->left=x;
    x->ht=height(x);
    y->ht=height(y);
    return(y);
}
node * AVL::RR(node *T)  <br>
{
    T=rotateleft(T);
    return(T);
}
node * AVL::LL(node *T)  <br>
{
    T=rotateright(T);
    return(T);
}
node * AVL::LR(node *T)  <br>
{
    T->left=rotateleft(T->left);
    T=rotateright(T);
    return(T);
}
node * AVL::RL(node *T)  <br>
{
    T->right=rotateright(T->right);
    T=rotateleft(T);
    return(T);
}  
int AVL::BF(node *T)  <br>
{
    int lh,rh;
    if(T==NULL)
    return(0);
    if(T->left==NULL)
        lh=0;
    else
        lh=1+T->left->ht;
    if(T->right==NULL)
        rh=0;
    else
        rh=1+T->right->ht;
    return(lh-rh);
}

void AVL::preorder1(node *T)  <br>
{
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<<T->key<<"(Bf="<<BF(T)<<")";
        preorder1(T->left);
        preorder1(T->right);
    }
}

void AVL::inorder1(node *T)  <br>
{
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        inorder1(T->left);
        cout<<" "<<T->key<<"(Bf="<<BF(T)<<")";
        inorder1(T->right);
    }
}

node * AVL::Delete1(node *T,char *x)  <br>
{       node *p;
    if(T==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
      {
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(x);i++)  <br>
        if(x[i] > T->key[i])                // insert in right subtree
        {
            T->right=Delete1(T->right,x);
            if(BF(T)==2)
                if(BF(T->left)>=0)
                    T=LL(T);
                else
                    T=LR(T);
            break;
        }
        else
            if(x[i]<T->key[i])
                {
                    T->left=Delete1(T->left,x);
                    if(BF(T)==-2)//Rebalance during windup
                        if(BF(T->right)<=0)
                            T=RR(T);
                        else


    T=RL(T);
                break;
                }

            else  <br>
              {
                //key to be deleted is found
                  if(T->right !=NULL)
                  {  //delete its inorder succesor
                      p=T->right;
                      while(p->left != NULL)
                      p=p->left;

                      strcpy(T->key,p->key);
                      T->right=Delete1(T->right,p->key);
                      if(BF(T)==2)//Rebalance during windup
                        if(BF(T->left)>=0)
                            T=LL(T);
                        else
                            T=LR(T);
                   }
                  else  <br>
                   return(T->left);
                  break;

              }
      }
    T->ht=height(T);
    return(T);
}
```